# How to move rent movies from iPod Touch to iMac?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, imac, movie

I moved rented movies from my iMac to my iPod Touch with iTunes to watch them outside, but now I want to watch some of them at home.

I tried to drag the rented movie in iPod Touch to iMac with iTunes, but nothing happened.

How do I move rented movies from an iPod Touch to an iMac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1657) - you should be able to move a rental that was first purchased and downloaded to a Mac as many times as you wish - but it can only be on one device at any point in time. You need to be connected to the internet when you move the rental file.

In your case, just find the rental on the device in iTunes and transfer it back to the iTunes library.

Expand the section named - **Can I play my rental on more than one device?** for the exact wording by Apple on this.

If you rented it on iOS - It's not possible without cracking the DRM as rentals from iOS or AppleTV stay on that one device and cannot be transferred.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I rent the movies on iMac then I moved them to iTouch.
I think iTune should warn about that when I move movies to iTouch, if I can't move them back to iMac.

Comment: I may have mis-read your question and given you bad information. See the FAQ at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1657 - but the important part is "You can move the movie between devices as many times as you wish during the rental period, but the movie can only exist on one device at a time." I had issues once and contacted billing and they promptly refunded my rental charge since I didn't know how to move it back to the computer and it expired unwatched.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I think you can use AirPlay from iPod Touch to your iMac. If it's not officially supported by Apple, then check out this [Jailbreak app](http://www.redmondpie.com/enable-airplay-from-iphone-ipad-ipod-touch-to-mac-with-airplayer/).